# Tableau not displaying all dates till current date

Tags: tableau-api

I have a tableau worksheet that shows a count of records by date. Current system date is Mar 14 but my dataset has data only till Mar 9. Is it possible to show dates from Mar 10 - Mar 14 even though there is no data for this time frame.

Given is a snapshot of my worksheet, kindly let me know how could I include all dates in the row even though there is no data for this time period.

[image]

Comment: can you attach workbook? also do you want to show bars of any length incase there is no data?

Answer (score 0):

Select discrete row it will show the date on a sheet

[image]

Comment: Hi Mehul thanks for the response. Changing to continuous changes the chart that I have in place. I cannot have this chart type change. Is there any work around where we can have the latest date shown (like system date) even though there are no records for those dates in the our dataset. Thanks again..